# How to redirect packet originated from localhost by using pf in os x yosemite?

Tags: nat, portforwarding, osx-yosemite

I want to redirect all outbound packets, 
which are originated from localhost and going to 192.168.6.10:1521, to 192.168.3.199:4002.
So, I tried as below, but it doesn't work.

```
sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
echo "
rdr pass proto tcp from any to 192.168.6.10 port 1521 -> 192.168.3.10 port 4002
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

There are many examples with ipfw or iptables,
but I couldn't find one working with pf in os x yosemite.

thanks in advance for your help :)